# Default buttonStyle

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have the following code for a "default" button style which is saved as a drawable (in drawable folder)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/yellow"
                android:centerColor="@color/orange"
                android:endColor="@color/yellow"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/green"
                android:centerColor="@color/lime"
                android:endColor="@color/green"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/white"
                android:centerColor="@color/silver"
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My very simple styles file is...

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@drawable/button_style</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And my colors file is set up as so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="lime">#00ff00</color>
    <color name="green">#008000</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
    <color name="silver">#c0c0c0</color>
    <color name="cyan">#00ffff</color>
    <color name="magenta">#ff00ff</color>
    <color name="orange">#ffa500</color>
    <color name="yellow">#ffff00</color>
    <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
    <color name="blue_gray">#98afc7</color>
    <color name="pink">#faafbe</color>
    <color name="brown">#a52a2a</color>
</resources>
```

However, my buttons are just appearing white with brown text. No outline, shape, gradient or anything.  Can anyone see what I'm obviously missing? It used to work in a previous project (which I no longer have) but now I can't for the life of me see why it's not displaying them correctly.

Thanks in advance, as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply your style using parent - android:style/Widget.Button like below,

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">  
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/brown</item>
</style>
```

and then apply that to your theme as,

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">         
     <item name="android:buttonStyle">>@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
 </style>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Welcome and nice to hear that. :)